# Creating a custom color plot with tones of colors

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Here is a sample set of data

```
m = {{3.37778, -2.73333, 21, 2}, {0.644444, 2.28889, 9, 3}, 
     {2.82222, -4.6, 13, 4}, {4.15556, -2.4, 17, 1}, 
     {-0.866667, -0.4, 6, 2}, {3.64444, 2.26667, 26, 4}, 
     {2.08889, 3.73333, 12, 3}, {1.73333, -4.48889, 12, 4}, 
     {-4.44444, -0.777778, 14, 2}, {-4.62222, 2.2, 12, 5}, 
     {0.977778, 0.755556, 18, 5}, {1.77778, -0.822222, 10, 1}, 
     {-1.02222, -1.86667, 11, 2}, {4.62222, 4.82222, 16, 3}, 
     {2., 2., 13, 3}, {0.666667, -1.88889, 8, 4}, 
     {-2.15556, 4.64444, 18, 5}, {-3.08889, 3.37778, 12, 5}, 
     {0.311111, -4.22222, 12, 4}, {-4.26667, -3.31111, 12, 2}};
```

The first two elements of the list represent the coordinates $(x,y)$, while the other two integers $k$, $n$, indicate other type of information.

Now let's setup a color code according to the second integer $n$ (last column)

```
getColor[m_List, i_Integer] := Module[{s = m[[i, 4]]},
Which[s == 0, Black, s == 1, Darker[Green], s == 2, Red, s == 3, 
Blue, s == 4, Magenta, s == 5, Orange, s == 6, Cyan, s == 7, 
Brown]];
```

and then create the graph

```
data = Table[{PointSize[0.02], getColor[m, i], Point[{m[[i, 1]], 
       m[[i, 2]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}];
S0 = Graphics[data];
```

[image]

Now I would like the to keep the colors according to $n$ but modify their tone according to the value of the first integer $k$ (third column). In particular, plot again the $(x,y)$ points in tones of green, red, blue, magenta, etc where darker color means higher value of $k$.

**EDIT**

Applying @J.M method to the actual data file the output is the follwoing

```
clist = {Black, Darker[Green], Red, Blue, Magenta, Orange, 
 Cyan, Brown};   
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], MapThread[{Darker[clist[[#[[4]] + 1]], #2],
 Point[Take[#, 2]]} &, {m, 1 - Rescale[m[[All, 3]]]}]}]
```

[image]

As we can see the entire plot is too dark and the colors are hardly distinguishable.

In case anyone wants to play with the actual [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/bxk7u00kje169rd/data_frac.out)

The resulted plot should be something like this

[image]

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $k$ bounded or unbounded?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the function `Lighter` with a `k` properly rescaled.

Comment: @J.M. Good question. $k$ is an integer. The code should read the data file and determine the minimum and maximum value of $k$ for every $n$.

Comment: @Xavier, yes, that's why I was asking about bounds on $k$. Would it be useful if, say $100$ and $500$ both gave colors that are visually the same?

Comment: @J.M. $k$ lies in the interval $[0,k_{max})$, where $k_{max}$ should be determined by reading the data file. The lower value of $k$ is always and for all $n$ equal to zero.

Comment: Try this: `clist = {Black, Darker[Green], Red, Blue, Magenta, Orange, Cyan, Brown}; Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], MapThread[{Darker[clist[[#[[4]] + 1]], #2], Point[Take[#, 2]]} &, {m, 1 - Rescale[m[[All, 3]]]}]}]`

Comment: @J.M. See my edit. Let's try this one: inserting by hand the maximum value of $k$.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Changing `Darker[clist[[#[[4]] + 1]]` to `Lighter[clist[[#[[4]] + 1]]` in J.M.'s code should produce a lighter plot. In case this is too light, you can think of changing in addition `1 - Rescale[m[[All, 3]]]` to `Rescale[m[[All, 3]]]`.

Comment: @Xavier The first one, changing `Darker[]` to `Lighter[]` produces too light plot, while if I set `Rescale[m[[All, 3]]]` instead of `1 - Rescale[m[[All, 3]]]` the tones completely disappear.

Comment: You could consider doing $\gamma$ correction; e.g. use `Darker[clist[[#[[4]] + 1]], #2^(4/5)]`.

Comment: @J.M. Again the plot is too dark. Is your code determining automatic the largest value of $k$ per color?

Comment: Supposedly. I was getting you to experiment with gamma correction, which you are apparently not familiar with; change the `4/5` in the previous snippet to any other number in $(0,1]$ until you see something you like.

Comment: @J.M. It's not working. I tried several values very close to 1 but the plot remains too dark. Let's try this one. Suppose the lowest value of $k$ is 0 (which is true) and the maximum value is 50 for all values of $n$ (colors). Then what modifications should be made in your piece of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    colors = Lighter[#, 0.2] & /@ {Black, Darker[Green], Red, Blue, Magenta, Orange, Cyan, Brown};

    cols = (Darker[colors[[#[[4]] + 1]], #[[3]]/40.] & /@ bigM);

    cols = Partition[cols, 451];

    Image[cols, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

[image]

EDIT (diagnostics):

[image]

Comment: `bigM` used but not set!

Comment: It's the data from your file...

Comment: When I evaluate `Image[]` I get the following error: Image::imgarray: "The specified argument {<<1>>} should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers."

Comment: Sounds like `cols` should be an array of rank 2 or 3! Which it should, and is in my case. I guess you haven't got your data in the same format as me, or you for that case. Make sure you import your data file such that it ends up in the same format as your example data - ie a 1d list of length 4 lists.

Comment: I use the same data file and I import is as `data = Import["data_frac.out", "Table"];` Then I just replaced `bigM` with `data`. The error is still present. BTW I use v9.0 of Mathematica.

Comment: The output of the Image ends like this: <<449>>, {RGBColor[0.575, <<20>>, 0.575], <<450>>}}, <<1>>]. Is this correct? What is this single <<1>>?

Comment: I've added a screengrab of the full code with some additional details present so hopefully you can fix your problem.

Comment: Hmm. I opened my second PC with v10 and everything is OK. So this code fails in v9. A couple of questions: (i) `Lighter[#, 0.2]` Why 0.2? (ii) `#[[3]]/40.` Why 40, what does this mean? (iii) `Partition[cols, 451];` Why 451? I noticed that in the plot there are some black circles. Is there a way to reduce them?

Comment: One last thing before accepting your answer. Could you put the image into a frame? I used `Show[... Frame->True]` but the frame labels range from 0 to 500 instead of -5 to 5.

Comment: @Vag, the `Partition[]` is for converting it into a 2-dimensional array of colors; as for your other questions, these seem to have been choices that gave something that looks good; you can tweak those parameters if needed.

Comment: @J.M. Many thanks for the explanations! Is there a way to add a correct frame? Now the range of the frame is from 0 to 500, while all points lie inside the square [-5,5].

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, it is rather rude to withhold your Accept subject to the poster making cosmetic tweaks which aren't even related to the question. Please try to judge answers based on how well they address the question you actually asked, not how well they meet your unstated final requirements. This is not a bespoke coding service! By all means ask a new question about framing images, however.